# Understand output of pwr.t2n.test in R

Tags: r

New to stats and R and was wondering if anyone can help me understand the output of the following code

```
pwr.t2n.test(n1=7561, n2=11531, d=NULL, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8)
```

output:

t test power calculation

```
         n1 = 7561
         n2 = 11531
          d = 0.04148028
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
alternative = two.sided
```

When I was going through the documentation it says d value of 0.2, 0.4, 0.8 corresponds to small, medium and large.. However, I get d as 0.04 when I run the above? What does it mean? Does it mean that I will be able to see and effect size of 0.0414 when I perform my tests?

On the other hand when I run the below code i.e. setting d = 0.8

```
pwr.t2n.test(n1=7561, n2=11531, d=0.8, sig.level = 0.05)
```

The output of power is 1 meaning it will be able to find the Type II error
    t test power calculation

```
         n1 = 7561
         n2 = 11531
          d = 0.8
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 1
alternative = two.sided
```

I am getting confused as I thought I will not be able to get a power of 1 for such high d value as my previous line gave a small value for d when power was 0.8

Can someone pls. explain and clear my understanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been six years I hope you've already found your answer. Otherwise, here's my take.

The effect size of .0415 in your first example means with your sample sizes, you have a 80% chance (your predetermined statistical power) of finding a significant difference between the two samples with an effect size as small as .0415, if your samples were indeed different from each other. It does not mean you will actually see a .0415 effect size when you run your test.

Regarding your second question, the statistical power has long exceeded 1 because of the large sample sizes. You don't need an effect size of .8 to reach 100% statistical power. See the code below.

```
d <- seq(.01, .1, len = 10)
pwr::pwr.t2n.test(n1=7561, n2=11531, d=d, sig.level = 0.05)

     t test power calculation 

             n1 = 7561
             n2 = 11531
              d = 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.1037289, 0.2718931, 0.5268369, 0.7712518, 0.9220074, 0.9818895, 0.9971987, 0.9997154, 0.9999812, 0.9999992
    alternative = two.sided
```

Note that, if your sample has an effect size of .08, you already have a 99.97% chance of finding a significant difference if there was indeed difference.